# Android get google account name that install package

Tags: android, package, google-account

Every application is installed using some google account. I need to know is there a way to retrieve user's google account name with which he installed a specific app. 
E.g. Instagram was installed using account A and Facebook using account B. I need to know these A and B.

Comment: I don't think it is possible

Answer (score 0):

As far as the google docs shows there are no user-accessible logs or other data on the app installation history. But you can do check the list of all the apps a user have installed on any device but wihtout any installation or uninstallation dates. Just get access to the user google account and you can see the list from this url : [APPS](https://play.google.com/apps). Not sure if there is an API for that tho.

## EDIT

in order to get all accounts on the device you can use [AccountManger](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html) something like `AccountManager.getAccounts` of course you need a permission for that `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />` and then iterate over the accounts get the list of apps and search for your specific app(s)